# successfully received bulk transfer data but its length was not enough

Tags: java, android, usb, transfer, bulk

I'm working on [bulk transfer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#bulkTransfer(android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint,%20byte[],%20int,%20int)) Android. I send and receive the data to/from USB successfully. The data that I send is `cbwBuffer` which is a command that tells USB that I want to read USB start in which sector and how many sector. Below is my code.

```
byte cswBuffer[] = new byte[18432];
iRes = conn.bulkTransfer(epOUT, cbwBuffer, 31, 500);//send data
iRes2 = conn.bulkTransfer(epIN, cswBuffer, 18432, 500);//receive data
```

The received data should be exactly 18432. However, **iRes2** equals to 16384, means that data that I received is only 16384 bytes, not 18432 bytes. I inspect the **cswBuffer**(received data) and find out that my data is only correct from 0 index to 16384 index but where is the rest? I mean the data was not enough. I need 18432-16384=2048 bytes more.

18432 means I read 36 sectors of my USB since 1 sector = 512 bytes. I just realized that if I read more than 32 sectors, I will always get 16384 bytes.

Comment: You will probably need to provide a bit more information and code to give your question a proper easy to understand context. As it stands, there is essentially no way for anyone to answer this. What is the bulkTransfer method? what is conn? Is the actual data more that 16384 bytes?

Comment: @NicRobertson I hope now its clear for readers to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion I found is the maximum data length can be received is 16384 bytes. If want more than that, just put another one of `iRes = conn.bulkTransfer(epIN, cswBuffer, remaining, 500)` and the remaining data will be received.

So I need to chunk the data where each data is at most 16384 bytes.

```
 if (noOfSector > 32) {
                //CHUNK DATA
                int maxLength = 16384;
                int lengthReceivedData = 0;
                int remaining;
                int chunkSize = (noOfSector + 32 - 1) / 32;int first= chuckSize;
                byte[] receivedData = new byte[maxLength];
                while (chunkSize > 1) {
                    cswBuffer = new byte[maxLength];
                    iRes = conn.bulkTransfer(epIN, cswBuffer, maxLength, 500);

                    if (chunkSize == first) {//if first time do this
                        receivedData = cswBuffer;
                    } else {

                        receivedData = concatenateByteArrays(receivedData, cswBuffer);
                    }

                    chunkSize--;
                    lengthReceivedData += maxLength;
                }
                remaining = sectorLength - lengthReceivedData;
                if (chunkSize == 1) {//last one sector
                    cswBuffer = new byte[remaining];
                    iRes = conn.bulkTransfer(epIN, cswBuffer, remaining, 500);
                    receivedData = concatenateByteArrays(receivedData, cswBuffer);
                    finalBuffer = receivedData;
                }
                //END CHUNK DATA
```